# SendGrid AddSubstitution() is not working every time (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

I have a SendGrid message that I'm constructing and testing in a dev environment. It points to a template that I've created in the SendGrid dashboard, and fills in some templated strings from the email body that look like this:

```
message.AddSubstitution("{Event__Acdy_For___Location1}", new List<string> { e.Location });
message.AddSubstitution("{Event__Acdy_For___Address1}", new List<string> { e.Address });
message.AddSubstitution("{Event__Acdy_For___City1}", new List<string> { e.City });
message.AddSubstitution("{Event__Acdy_For___State1}", new List<string> { e.State });
message.AddSubstitution("{Event__Acdy_For___Zip1}", new List<string> { e.Zipcode });
```

If I send this every minute or so I'm noticing that some emails have empty strings in these substitution spots, where the same exact email (going through the same construct from my end) display everything fine.

If I rapid fire these, it's completely hit or miss; I'll get an email for each send, but only a couple actually fill in the substitutions.

Has anyone seen this before? I see no errors on my end or in SendGrid's dashboard.

Comment: Have same issue. Have you able to find out if that is caused by error in the api. What did you use instead?

Comment: Check your payload - what is been sent to the api. I suspect in the personalization array you have 2 email to.